# Laravel remove directory

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to delete a directory in Laravel 5.1 like this:

```
use Storage;

public function deleteUser(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->id); 
    Storage::deleteDirectory('/files/'.$user->id);
    $user->delete();
    $user->websites()->delete();
    return redirect('/')->with('status','Customer removed');
}
```

The directory isn't going away. But the user is successfully removed.

Here is the documentation:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#deleting-files

Why is this not working?

Comment: first check the permission to delete that directory.

Comment: If permissions are correct, I would say something with your path is wrong. You could try to list all directories to see if your path is correct. Try `$directories = Storage::directories('/files/');` and `dd($directories)` to output all directories inside `/files/`

Comment: as stated by @ImtiazPabel  permissions could be causing the issue. check the log and see if you see the error for no permissions. to test if the permissions are causing the issue chmod -R 777 files /

Comment: i agree with @SariYono first check file permission,your project error log.If not found any error in your project log then check your server error log.

Comment: I had the same problem, try to clean the directory first. Use: Storage::cleanDirectory($directory); before Storage::deleteDirectory();

Comment: @derdida thanks but when I do that I gives me an error: Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::cleanDirectory

Comment: Try to include the "File" Facade and try File::cleanDirectory($directory);

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the Storage:deleteDirectory command too. Later I found out it could be easily done with the following command:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`    `File::deleteDirectory('/Users/zawad/web/storage/app/sleepdata/DirectoryToBeDeleted');`

The argument is the absolute path to the directory which is to be deleted. You can find the root of the path by running the `pwd` command in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleteDirectory( $path ) {
     File::cleanDirectory( $path );
     Storage::deleteDirectory( $path );
     rmdir( $path );
}
```

Comment: Works in laravel 5, bare in mind that Luke's parameter is incorrect and should be `$path` to be used throughout the rest of the function.